# Drain a CR4250 battery

Tags: batteries, discharge

I have a CR4250 battery that I need to drain but I don't have a multimeter or any other tools/wire. I've already tried soaking in saltwater for an hour and it still works. I also attached two bobby pins to the + and - sides, then wrapped the exposed ends in aluminum foil and then connected them. I let that sit for an hour or so and the battery still works. Any suggestions? I'd like to do something fast.

Comment: Do you mean CR2450?

Comment: Why do you need to drain the battery?

Comment: why are you doing this?

Comment: What is your definition of "still works"?

Answer (score 0):

I'd stick it in a paper clip making sure each side of the battery is making good contact with the paperclip, or wrap the whole battery tight with aluminum foil.
It will take some time to drain the battery because that style battery has a high internal impedance.  So the best you can do is short the battery and wait for a few hours.

Be sure to not do this with other types of batteries!  A lead acid battery like what you will find in a car is capable of supplying hundreds of amps which can cause too small of wire (or a paper clip) to burn.  The only reason you can get away with this for your typical CR2450 battery is because the battery's internal impedance limits the max current it can supply to less than an amp.